# Realm sharing database through Groups with app extension

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an app with a today extension. In appDelegate.swift for the main app:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let directory: NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.Hobo.RealmDatabase")!
    var config = Realm.Configuration()
    config.fileURL = directory.filePathURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm")
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    return true
}
```

In my todayExtension's viewDidload:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let directory: NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.Hobo.RealmDatabase")!
    var config = Realm.Configuration()
    config.fileURL = directory.filePathURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm")
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    let realm = try! Realm()
}
```

When I create an object in my main app, it persists in the database. However when I try to read the number of objects from todayExtensionViewController, it returns 0, meaning no objects were created.

I am confused because since both the apps getting the same Realm data from the same location, isn't it supposed to "share" the data?

I'm using groups to share data between apps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An obvious question, but have you verified that both pieces of code are computing the same path?

Comment: Did you set appGroups in your scheme? This article may help you: http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions

Comment: @bdash Yes I have verified, they both lead to the same path.

Comment: @PiratM Thanks for the help! But yes, I have set it as my scheme.

Comment: Did you make sure that you don't access the Realm before your `viewDidLoad` method is invoked in your extension?

Comment: @RaymondMoay, did you find any answer?

Comment: please use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38691962/4935811