# How can app extension access files in containing app Documents/ folder

Tags: ios, filesystems, ios-app-extension

In the app extension is there a way to get images generated from the containing app which is store in  /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application//Documents// folder?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In order to make files available to app extension you have to use `Group Path`, as App Extension can't access app's Document Folder, for that you have follow these steps,

1. Enable **App Groups** from **Project Settings-> Capabilities**.
2. Add a group extension something like `group.yourappid`.
3. Then use following code.

   ```
   NSString *docPath=[self groupPath];

   NSArray *contents=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docPath error:nil];

   NSMutableArray *images=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

       for(NSString *file in contents){
           if([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"]){
               [images addObject:[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]];
           }
       }


   -(NSString *)groupPath{
        NSString *appGroupDirectoryPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:group.yourappid].path;

       return appGroupDirectoryPath;
   }
   ```

You can add or change the path extension as per your image extensions you are generating.

**Note - Remember you need to generate the images in the group folder rather than in Documents Folder, so it is available to both app and extension.**

Cheers.

**Swift 3 Update**

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let url = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "YOUR_GROUP_ID")?.appendingPathComponent("logo.png")

// Write to Group Container            
if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {

    let image = UIImage(named: "name")
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
    fileManager.createFile(atPath: url.path as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
}

// Read from Group Container - (PushNotification attachment example)              
// Add the attachment from group directory to the notification content                    
if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "", url: url!) {

    bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]

    // Serve the notification content
    self.contentHandler!(self.bestAttemptContent!)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this totally works! Now I need to transfer all the images to AppGroup//Documents/ folder.

Comment: hi @iphonic you have any idea for this question     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547930/how-can-i-create-and-access-share-app-group-document-directory?noredirect=1#comment97797926_55547930

Comment: I want to write logs in extensions project , i have create the file in app group shared folder but still it could not write data on file , do you know why ?

Comment: @Anita have you found a solution for logging in extension to shared container?

Comment: Yes , we can not access the docuent folder for app accessing file , in app and extension you need to use shared folder 

Check this : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html