# how can I create and access share app group document directory?

Tags: swift, custom-keyboard, ios-app-group, document-directory

i am using custom keyboard extension then download keyboard theme from server and save in to app document directory but app document directory can not access in custom keyboard extension so, required to share app group directory. how can i do please help me.

Now i am trying this but its not working.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
                if let directory = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.companyname.appname") {
                    //let newDirectory = directory.appendingPathComponent(dataPath)
                    newDirectory = directory.appendingPathComponent("MyDirectory")
                    try? fileManager.createDirectory(at: newDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
                    print(newDirectory.path)
                }
```

Comment: Did you enable app groups on both targets?

Comment: yes already do this

Comment: Use the directory which you have created above to save files instead of app document directory.

Comment: i am using for get data in extension but its not working like as under

Comment: let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if let directory = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.anishmodan.fontapp") {
            
            print(directory.path)
            
            let pathUrl = directory.appendingPathComponent("Test.jpg")
            
            print(pathUrl.path as Any)
            
            let Image1 = UIImage(contentsOfFile: pathUrl.path)!
            //after set this on imageview
        }

Comment: any idea how can i open this file :  /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/9340E258-6816-4EB4-83E7-34EFDFEA86DB/Test.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved

```
  let fileManager = FileManager.default
                                        let url = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.companyname.appname")?.appendingPathComponent("logo.png")

                                        // store image in group container
                                        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url!.path) {

                                            let image =  UIImage(data: data)
                                            let imageData : Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!) as! Data
                                            fileManager.createFile(atPath: url!.path as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
                                        }

//ACCESS THIS or get store image 
 let Image1 = UIImage(contentsOfFile: (url?.path)!)!
```

Comment: I want to write logs in extensions project , i have create the file in app group shared folder but still it could not write data on file , do you know why ?